# Which pronoun: ‘them’ or ‘themselves’?

Tags: pronouns

Which would make a more suitable pronoun in the following sentence: them or themselves?

The boys wear sunglasses to shield them / themselves from the hot sun.

Answer (score 1):

The boys **shielded themselves** from the hot sun **with an umbrella**.

The boys **shielded their eyes from the sun with sunglasses**.

If you are only shielding your eyes, you probably wouldn't say shield yourself but rather shield your eyes. If you are shielding your whole body, shield themselves is right.